# Understanding python subprocess.check_output's first argument and shell=True

Tags: python, linux, shell, subprocess

I'm confused on how to correctly use Python's subprocess module, specifically, the check_output method's first argument and the `shell` option.  Check out the output from the interactive prompt below.  I pass the first argument as a list and depending on whether `shell=True` is set, I get different output.  Can someone explain why this is and the output that is outputted?

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello World!"])
'Hello World!\n'
>>> subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello World!"], shell=True)
'\n'
```

Now when I pass the first argument as a simple string instead of a list, I get this nasty stack trace.  Why is that and what's going on here?

```
>>> subprocess.check_output("echo Hello World!")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 537, in check_output
process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1228, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

However, when I turn on shell=True, it then works perfectly:

```
>>> subprocess.check_output("echo Hello World!", shell=True)
'Hello World!\n'
```

So I'm a little confused, it works when the first arg is in a list WITHOUT `shell=True` and then works as a simple string WITH `shell=True`.  I'm not understanding what `shell=True` does and the difference between passing the first arg as a list vs a string.

Answer (score 11):

From the documentation of [`Popen`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

> The shell argument (which defaults to `False`) specifies whether to use
>   the shell as the program to execute. If shell is `True`, it is
>   recommended to pass `args` as a string rather than as a sequence.
>
> On Unix with `shell=True`, the shell defaults to `/bin/sh`. **If args is a
>   string, the string specifies the command to execute through the shell**.
>   This means that the string must be formatted exactly as it would be
>   when typed at the shell prompt. This includes, for example, quoting or
>   backslash escaping filenames with spaces in them. **If args is a
>   sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any
>   additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell
>   itself**. That is to say, `Popen` does the equivalent of:
>
> ```
> Popen(['/bin/sh', '-c', args[0], args[1], ...])
> ```
>
> On Windows with `shell=True`, the COMSPEC environment variable specifies
>   the default shell. The only time you need to specify `shell=True` on
>   Windows is when the command you wish to execute is built into the
>   shell (e.g. `dir` or `copy`). You do not need `shell=True` to run a batch
>   file or console-based executable.

In your case, since `echo` is a shell built-in when launched with `shell=True`, if you want to pass arguments to the `echo` command you *must* either write the command as a string or pass a sequence that has the *whole* command as a string as first element. Other elements of the sequence are passed as arguments *to the shell*, not to the command you are invoking.

In *some* OSes `echo` is *also* a program (usually `/bin/echo`). This explains why your first example didn't raise an exception but outputs `'\n'` instead of the expected `'Hello, World!\n'`: the `/bin/echo` command was executed without arguments, because the argument was "consumed" by the shell.

The error raised when calling:

```
subprocess.check_output("echo Hello World!")
```

is due to the fact that, since you did *not* use `shell=True`, python is trying to execute the program `echo Hello World!` i.e. a program that has the name `echo<space>Hello<space>World!`. It *is* a valid program name, but you there's no program with that name, hence the exception.

Comment: It seems like an API design deficiency. `shell` being `True/False` is not prominent enough to justify such drastic (but silent) change in the meaning of the first argument (the command). btw, new [`asyncio` module](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#running-subprocesses) uses two different functions instead: `subprocess_exec` and `subprocess_shell` to run a subprocess and a shell command correspondingly.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian They should probably have added a `shell_args` parameter instead of re-using `args`.

Comment: yeah, `len(args) > 1 and shell=True` is an error in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you use `shell=True`, you enter as the first argument to `check_output` a string in quotes that represents what you normally enter into a shell. "On Unix with shell=True, the shell defaults to `/bin/sh`." This gives you all the shell features. "This means that the string must be formatted exactly as it would be when typed at the shell prompt." [See Popen](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor)