# Executing a Linux shellscript

Tags: python, popen

I'm trying to execute a shellscript from Python that takes ipaddress as a parameter,

I'm using the below command but get an error, I need to execute this shellscript as a Sudo user..

Error:-

```
[root@linuxhost web]# python test.py
29575
usage: sudo [-D level] -h | -K | -k | -V

usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-D level] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user

            name|#uid]



process = subprocess.Popen(['sudo','/usr/local/bin/test.sh','127.0.0.1'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
process.wait()
```

I tried calling the shellscript by directly calling using sudo and still it fails..

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['sudo /usr/local/bin/test.sh','127.0.0.1'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
```

Comment: try sudo python test.py (and remove sudo from the script)

Comment: Sometimes it is handy for scripts to ask for root password instead of failing and requiring the user to re-run the script.

Comment: related: [Understanding python subprocess.check_output's first argument and shell=True](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21029154/4279)

Comment: unrelated: don't use `subprocess.PIPE` unless you consume the pipes. It may stall the child process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't combine list args with `shell=True`. Use something like

```
process = subprocess.Popen('sudo /usr/local/bin/test.sh 127.0.0.1',
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
```

or do not use `shell=True`

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['sudo','/usr/local/bin/test.sh','127.0.0.1'],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: You mean none of them are? What are the problems you encounter?

Comment: with list args and no shell=True, I get this error------ File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: This usually means the executable was not found. Try `/usr/bin/sudo` instead of just `sudo` (in case sudo is not in your path).