# How do I to get Python 2.7 to handle a shell script that has "&& exit"?

Tags: python, linux, shell, python-2.7, tkinter

I have a Desktop Icon(Linux Mint system) that calls a script (conky) but also needs to exit so I don't have a terminal window open all the time.  I'm trying to convert this to an onscreen python button.

I can get Python Button to run the script but I can't get it to close the terminal once the script is up and running fine.

This is the normal command: `/home/user/.conky_start.sh && exit`

Current Python Button Script:

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
import subprocess

top = Tkinter.Tk()

def run_conky():
   subprocess.call(['/home/user/.conky_start.sh', '&&', 'exit'], shell=True)

B = Tkinter.Button(top, text ="Conky", command = run_conky)

B.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: [Don't use a list argument together with shell=True.](http://bugs.python.org/issue21347)

Comment: Do you want to exit the Python script after `.conky_start.sh` is started?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding python subprocess.check\_output's first argument and shell=True](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21029154/understanding-python-subprocess-check-outputs-first-argument-and-shell-true)

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
subprocess.call('/home/user/.conky_start.sh && exit', shell=True)
```

When `shell=True` the first argument to `call` must be *a string* which represent the command line. If you pass a list the first element is used as command line and the other arguments are passed to the underlying shell as options.

In other words, the `&& exit` in your code was never executed because it was passed as options to the shell (which probably simply ignored the unrecognized options).

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21029154/510937) question for more information about arguments to `subprocess` functions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Actually, that was the first thing I tried.  Sadly, this does not make a difference to the exit issue.

Answer (score 0):

To exit the Python script after the attempt to start the shell script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import Tkinter

root = Tkinter.Tk()

def start_conky():
    try:
        subprocess.Popen(['/home/user/.conky_start.sh']) # don't wait
    finally:
        root.destroy() # exit the GUI

Tkinter.Button(root, text="Conky", command=start_conky).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Awesome, this works and gets me one step further!  Hmm, while the script did exit, it started outputting more info.

One of the other scripts that gets called looks for a running media player to display song title/artist. It kinda complains that it can't find anything constantly.  Will have to look into that another day.  Wish I could upvote but aparently I need 9 more reputation points :/  Consider this an upvote :)