# converting command line syntax to os.system call or subprocess cal; in python

Tags: python, linux, bash

I can run this command `cat /home/norman/conf/second.txt | sort | uniq > /home/norman/conf/third.txt`
but would like to use an os,system call or a subprocess call but whatever I have tried always causes an error.
I have tried such things as `command = "cat /home/norman/conf/second.txt | sort | uniq > /home/norman/conf/third.txt".split()
subprocess.call(command)`
but get

> cat: '|': No such file or directory
>   cat: sort: No such file or directory
>   cat: '|': No such file or directory
>   cat: uniq: No such file or directory
>   cat: '>': No such file or directory

Comment: Take a look at this question too: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21029154/510937

Comment: Sorry it doesn't seem to be a duplicate to me. I want to send stdout to a file not display it on the screen  so I can use it to do further processing of the data. In any case I have found out how to do it now.

Comment: This exact problem can be done even simpler in actual Python code: `with open('/home/norman/conf/second.txt', 'r') as f: result = sorted(set(f))`.

Comment: @Buteman Just redirect `stdout` to an open file object by assigning `stdout=my_file` (open the file as `with open(<path>, 'w') as my_file`.